# SLD, combine variable and propertyIsEqualTo

Tags: geoserver, sld, css

I'm trying to make simple switch (if if else) statement in SLD with value coming from variable.

I'm calling Goeserver with parameter `env=imageSize:A4`.

Now based on that, I'd like to set `cssProperty` according to what value gets passed on. Pseudocode:

```
IF imageSize = A4
    cssProperty = 2
IF imageSize = A3
    cssProperty = 3
ELSE
    cssProperty = 1
```

I've come up with this:

```
<sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">
  <ogc:Function name="if_then_else">
    <ogc:Function name="EqualTo">
      <ogc:PropertyName>pageSize</ogc:PropertyName>
      <ogc:Literal>A4</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
    <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
</sld:CssParameter>
```

I can't get this to work, and after that I still need to implement second if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function names are case sensitive so your code will work with `equalTo` instead of `EqualTo`. Also your `pageSize` variable is an [environment variable](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/substitution.html#variable-substitution-in-sld) not a property.

But in your case it would probably be easier to use a `recode` function:

```
<sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">
    <ogc:Function name="Recode">
      <ogc:Function name="env">
         <ogc:Literal>pageSize</ogc:Literal>
         <ogc:Literal>DEFAULT</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:Function>
      <ogc:Literal>A4</ogc:Literal>
      <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal> 
      <ogc:Literal>A3</ogc:Literal>
      <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal> 
      <ogc:Literal>DEFAULT</ogc:Literal>
      <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
     </ogc:Function>
 </sld:CssParameter>
```

Then make sure your